# .net error visual studio attachment

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

[.Net 4.0 and Below Unknown Error, Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l794w.png)

[Debug Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTQBv.png)

Hi Guys, I have a clean installation of windows 10 and a fresh install of Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, but while creating a new project targeting a .Net 4.0 and Below(3.5, 3.0, 2.0) It gives me an error, When i change the Debug option to x86 target machine instead of ANY CPU, it didn't give me an error. my question is, why is it happening ? .NET 3.0 is a requirement for my projects. Thanks in Advance. I have included images.

Comment: You have to apply all updates to both Windows and VS. Meanwhile, .NET Framework 3.0 and 4.0 both expired, and you need to be on .NET Framework 3.5.1 and 4.5.2 at least.

Comment: Yes, I already installed the updates for windows 10 Fall Creators Update and VS2015 Updates. If that's the case then why is it my other PC doesn't give me the same error when creating a .NET 2.0 Project in VS2012? thanks.

Comment: @Jerwen try to update with update 3, it should work.

Comment: @Adrian, This is actually the latest VS2015 Update. .